# What political system does Star Trek's Federation operate under?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-tos, politics, government

I've watched all of the Original Series and The Next Generation, and bits of Deep Space 9 and Voyager, all of the movies, but none of the more recent series, or the books. In all of the material I've seen, events tend to mostly focus on Starfleet (understandable, in that the action takes place on Starfleet ships/stations, and the main characters are Starfleet officers). I'm curious how the non-military, non-exploratory parts of the Federation government work.

Clearly, there are individual planetary governments, and some kind of federal government "on top of" that. Does each planetary government send delegates to some central governing body? Do they get population-based representation, one vote per planet, or what? Does the Federation have a "security council" like the United Nations, where some members are "more equal than others"?

What is the Federation government charged with? They're in charge of scientific exploration/defense (via Starfleet), but what else do they do?

I've read the [Memory Alpha page](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/United_Federation_of_Planets#Government) on the Federation, and it's very vague, mostly just references to government bureaus or departments that are off-hand mentioned in one episode or another. I figured there might be sources with more detail - like the Enterprise series, which I gather has to do with the early period of the Federation, or maybe in another medium altogether.

Comment: I know the humans, Vulcans, Andorians, and Tellarites have slightly more standing than others, since they founded the Federation, but I'm pretty certain that's more courtesy than anything else.

Comment: http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/United_Federation_of_Planets#Government

Comment: @muistooshort, I did read the memory-alpha article, but it was unsurprisingly light on detail. Mostly just links to one-paragraph descriptions of events from various episodes. Maybe that's all there is?

Comment: @MarkBessey Pretty much.  As it says in the blurb at that link, `The exact nature of the government of the Federation has never been made clear on screen.` and `The exact division of powers between the Federation government and the governments of its member worlds is unknown`

Comment: A lot can be inferred from small mentions here and there in the various episodes and movies (quite possibly more than would fit in an answer, given all your sub-questions), but little about the government itself has been made explicit.

Comment: Wasn't Starfleet involved with relocation of the founders of the Marqui, before they were the Marqui? Starfleet was also in charge of prisons. Anything that needs labour usually involves Starfleet with the Federation governing the overall duty and allocation.

Comment: Aside, it's also a good idea to include that you've read what was on Memory Alpha and found it lacking, otherwise you'd likely just get a lot of quotes from there.  It's one of the best Star Trek references online.

Comment: I think the writers kept this deliberately vague in most cases to enhance general audience appeal.

Comment: ENT takes place 10 to 6 years before the founding of the Federation, so no, there's really nothing there

Comment: We know that the Federation was founded the year after the Earth-Romulus War ended, and have a very generalised, rough outline of how it operates. That's it. To my knowledge, no canon source, nor ambiguously-canon novels and comics, has offered any elucidation as to the exact nature of the Federation's federal system. Presumably the Federation handles foreign policy and defence, but individual members handle their own worlds/ colonies. The relationship between member-worlds and their colonies has also never been explored adequately.

Comment: Come on, no quotes from Roddenberry?

Comment: One thing it's important to recognize: several member states maintain their own fleets.  While humans seem to only use Federation ships, there is such a thing as a "Vulcan ship" which is set apart.  That, to me, makes it seem like more of an alliance like the European Union, United Nations or NATO: all the parties are united in many things (no doubt aided by the utopian social attitudes of the era), but they still retain more autonomy than the states of the USA.  There's no such thing as a "Texan fleet."

Comment: A Federation is type of government. A federation (Latin: foedus, foederis, 'covenant'), also known as a federal state, is a political entity characterized by a union of partially self-governing states or regions under a central (federal) government. In a federation, the self-governing status of the component states, as well as the division of power between them and the central government, are typically constitutionally entrenched and may not be altered by a unilateral decision of either party, the states or the federal political body.

Comment: I imagine Earth government operates mainly as a meritocracy, with a large helping of democratic socialism on the side.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [Starfleet Technical Manual](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Star_Fleet_Technical_Manual) contains a complete copy of the "**Articles of Federation**" that were agreed by the original members of the United Federation of Planets on Stardate 0965.

Although this book is generally considered 'non-canon', material from it has been used in several episodes of TNG, Trek films and throughout DS9 and Voyager.

As you can see, the [Federation Charter](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Charter_of_the_United_Federation_of_Planets) is very heavily modeled on the [United Nations Charter](http://www.un.org/en/documents/charter/).

I'll paraphrase the main points;

> **Primary Articles**
>
> 0. The primary purpose of the United Federation of Planets (UFP) is the
>    **mutual pursuit of peace** as well as cultural, financial, humanitarian
>    and social interaction.
>
> 0.1) The UFP will not intervene in "matters which are essentially the domestic jurisdiction of any planetary social
> system"
>
> 0.2) The UFP is based on the Sovereign Equality of all of its members.
>
> 1. Membership of the Federation is subject to the unanimous agreement
>    of the Supreme Assembly.
> 2. The Supreme Assembly of the Federation can temporarily or
>    permanently remove UFP membership.
> 3. The main bodies of the UFP are; The Supreme Assembly, The
>    Federation Council, The Economic and Social Council, The
>    Interplanetary Court of Justice, The Star Fleet and the Secretariat.
>
> **Supreme Assembly**
>
> 1. The Supreme Council consists of all members of the UFP and is responsible for the "peaceful adjustment" of any
>    situation involving UFP members, managing the budget of the UFP and
>    promoting mutual cooperation between UFP members.
> 2. The expense of the UFP is borne by all members, as apportioned by
>    the Supreme Assembly.
> 3. Each planet has one vote on the Supreme Assembly.
> 4. Supreme Assembly unanimity is required for decisions regarding UFP
>    membership, suspension and expulsion as well as setting and apportioning the budget of the UFP.
> 5. The Supreme Assembly will vote for a 'President of the Supreme
>    Assembly' each session
>
> **Federation Council**
>
> 1. The Federation Council will consist of 11 members.
> 2. There are 5 permanent members of the Federation Council; Earth, The
>    Planetary Confederation of 40 Eridani, the United Planets of 61 Cygni,
>    The Star Empire of Epsilon Indii and the Alpha Centauri Concordium of
>    Planets.
> 3. All other members of the UFP will periodically take seats on the
>    Federation Council
> 4. The Federation Council is responsible for prompt action regarding
>    interplanetary security (including the prosecution of sanctions,
>    blockades and the severance of diplomatic relations) unless explicitly
>    over-ridden by a unanimous vote of the Supreme Assembly.
>
> **Trusteeship Council**
>
> 1. The Trusteeship Council will accept and
>    arbitrate on petitions and disputes involving UFP members.
>
> **Star Fleet**
>
> 1. "There is established an Star Fleet as an armed
>    peace-keeping force of the UFP".
> 2. The Star Fleet is permanently under the control of the Federation
>    Council.
> 3. The Star Fleet is to be used for scientific exploration when not
>    being used for the purposes of maintaining interplanetary peace.
>
> **Economic + Social Council**
>
> 1. The Economic council will aim to secure higher standards of living, full employment and fundamental
>    freedoms for all UFP Citizens
> 2. UFP members agree to fundamentally accept the rights of all
>    intelligent lifeforms regardless of gender, culture, language or
>    religion.
> 3. UFP members should act as "good neighbours" toward non-UFP members
>    in outlying regions.

[image: Articles of Federation]

---

Ronald D. Moore spoke to this in an interview [on AOL](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Memory_Alpha:AOL_chats/Ronald_D._Moore/ron014.txt). In brief, the show's writers have gone to some lengths (since the 1960s) to keep the whole business of the governance of Earth and the Federation as opaque as possible, in order to allow maximum latitude for storytelling, inventing various councils and elected positions as they see fit.

> Q. In "Homefront" the President said he never sought this position.
> DOes this mean the Federation president is Appointed?  Why no
> election? And why does the Federation President put Earth into a state
> of Emergency?  Does Earth not have it's own Government like all the
> other members of the Federation?
>
> **RDM:** We assume the Fed President was duly elected, but that he reluctantly was induced to run for the position.  As for the Earth Govt vs. Fed Govt issue, this was something we wrestled with in the story break.  We wanted to tell the story of an attempted military coup of the Federation and that meant dealing with the Fed president.  However, that meant the troops "in the streets" had to be on Earth and that Earth itself had to be under martial law since the Fed is headquartered on Earth.  We discussed having the Prez "federalize" the Earth defense forces or supercede the authority of an indigenous Earth Govt, but the story kept getting too complicated and we didn't want to start mentioning all these other players and organizations that we weren't going to see. **So in the end, we skirted the issue of who actually governs Earth.  Personally, I think there is an Earth Govt that operates like more powerful versions of States do in the US system, but this is all VERY murky water.  Gene was pretty smart back in the 60s when he decided not to discuss the exact outcome of Earth's political/social/economic future and we've come about as close to doing just that as I think we should.**

Comment: Worth noting that this book wasn't created by anyone involved in production, but by a technical artist named Franz Joseph who started it as an exercise to help Trek fans he knew with model-building, and after it became popular Paramount licensed it (story [here](http://graphic-engine.swarthmore.edu/franz-joseph-and-star-treks-blueprint-culture/)). The "background information" section of the Memory Alpha article says "this book is now considered to be non-canonical", although it notes some starship designs from the book later were mentioned or appeared on display screens in the movies.

Comment: @hypnosifl - As a licensed property, I tend to err on the side of caution, canon until contradicted. Since elements of the constitution have been included in epidodes, it's not contradicted.

Comment: Do you have access to the book [Star Trek Federation: The First 150 Years](http://www.amazon.com/Star-Trek-Federation-First-Years/dp/1781169152)? This was commissioned by CBS rather than something independently created which Paramount just retroactively approved, and the author [David Goodman](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/David_A._Goodman) was a writer for *Enterprise*, so I think it would be closer to "official", and it might have info on the political structure. One of the images on Amazon shows the first page of the "Articles of Federation" which differ from those in the tech manual.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - I'm just tracking it down. It seems a lot more heavily influenced by the US constitution.

Answer (score 13):

The other answers don't address the basic question of whether the Federation is a democracy, so I just wanted to point out that in the TOS episode ["Errand of Mercy"](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/27.htm), we do get confirmation that it is, in the following exchange between Captain Kirk and Klingon Commander Kor:

> KIRK: Something was destroyed? Nothing inconsequential, I hope.
>
> KOR: Hardly. They were quite important to us, but they can be replaced. You of the Federation, you are much like us.
>
> KIRK: We're nothing like you. **We're a democratic body.**

And in the *Deep Space Nine* episode ["Once More Unto The Breach"](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/557.htm), we meet with an aged Kor, who tells Worf "Worf, you've been living among this democratic rabble for too long", which seems to indicate the Federation is still democratic in this period.

In addition, we know from *Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home* that the Federation had a deliberative body called the "Federation Council":

[image]

The [Memory Alpha article](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Federation_Council) mentions a number of episodes that have referenced this Council. In the *Deep Space Nine* episode ["Homefront"](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/483.htm) it was confirmed that the Federation President at the time, [Jaresh-Inyo](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Jaresh-Inyo), had been elected to the position:

> JARESH-INYO: I never sought this job. I was content to simply represent my people on the Federation Council. When they asked me to submit my name for election, I almost said no. Today I wish I had.

And in the *Deep Space Nine* episode ["Paradise Lost"](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/484.htm) when Admiral Leyton hoped to oust Jaresh-Inyo and give Starfleet direct command of the Federation, Sisko objected that this would make the Federation into a military dictatorship, which seems to indicate that under the existing system Starfleet was under the command of elected leaders:

> SISKO: Admiral, do you realise what's going on here? Even if you win, even if you do manage to oust Jaresh-Inyo, you still lose. We all lose.
>
> LEYTON: I can't say I agree with you.
>
> SISKO: Do you think other Federation worlds are going to sit back and let their President be replaced by a military dictatorship?
>
> LEYTON: Hardly a dictatorship, Ben.
>
> SISKO: Overthrowing a legitimately elected President and giving Starfleet direct control over the government? It sounds like a dictatorship to me, and I'm sure I'm not the only one who thinks so.

The *Next Generation* episode ["The Perfect Mate"](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/221.htm) also gives onscreen confirmation that the Federation is a *constitutional* democracy, with provisions for the "fundamental rights" of individuals, which precluded treating sentient beings as property:

> RIKER: You mean you're using this ship to transport a sentient being as property?
>
> BRIAM: Not as property, as a gift, and I was concerned that you might not entirely understand.
>
> PICARD: Your concern was justified, Ambassador.
>
> KAMALA: You're angry. Why?
>
> PICARD: There is a provision in the Federation Constitution that protects an individual's fundamental rights.

In the *TNG* episode ["The Drumhead"](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/195.htm) we learn that another "fundamental principle" of the Constitution was the "Seventh Guarantee", which apparently dealt with the right to refuse to answer certain questions in court:

> WORF: But we know there is a traitor here. J'Dan has admitted his guilt.
>
> PICARD: That's true, and he will stand for his crimes.
>
> WORF: Tarses has all but done the same.
>
> PICARD: How?
>
> WORF: He refused to answer the question about his Romulan grandfather.
>
> PICARD: That is not a crime, Worf. Nor can we infer his guilt because he didn't respond.
>
> WORF: Sir, if a man were not afraid of the truth, he would answer.
>
> PICARD: Oh, no. We cannot allow ourselves think that. The Seventh Guarantee is one of the most important rights granted by the Federation. We cannot take a fundamental principle of the Constitution and turn it against a citizen.

When the Federation was first founded in 2161, a document called the [Charter of the United Federation of Planets](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Federation_Charter) was ratified (not to be confused with the [Starfleet Charter](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Starfleet_Charter), since as noted above they are distinct organizations). The Memory Alpha article comments on the uncertain relation between the Charter and the Constitution:

> The relationship between the Constitution of the United Federation of Planets and the Federation Charter is unclear. Both contain rights for individuals; as Sisko put it in DS9: "Accession": "caste-based discrimination goes against the Federation Charter". It is most likely that the Charter describes the requirements for entry of a planet into the Federation (e.g., no entry if caste-based discrimination is in place), while the Constitution describes the principles, governing structure, and citizen rights once becoming a member (e.g., rights against self-incrimination).

Part of the Charter was visible in the *Voyager* episode ["The Void"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Void_(episode)), and the Memory Alpha article notes that it's a rewording of the United Nations charter (as are the "Articles of Federation" from the non-canon-but-influential *Star Fleet Technical Manual* quoted in @Valorum's answer):

> CHARTER OF THE UNITED FEDERATION OF PLANETS
>
> "We the lifeforms of the United Federation of Planets determined to save succeeding generations from the scourge of war, and to reaffirm faith in the fundamental rights of sentient beings, in the dignity and worth of all lifeforms, in the equal rights of members of planetary systems large and small, and to establish conditions under which justice and respect for the obligations arising from treaties and other sources of interstellar law can be maintained, and to promote social progress and better standards of living on all worlds..."

Comment: For the record, while the Federation Council is a democracy, the individual planets, planetary federations and stellar empires that make up the Federation are free to elect (or appoint) their representative however they see fit. That presumably includes *not* using democratic systems.

Comment: @Valorum - Good point--it could be like the U.N. in that sense, although given the respect shown for democratic values by human characters, I think it's likely that at least the Earth officials were democratically elected.

Comment: Oh, definitely. In Enterprise we see that there are "Ministers", implying some sort of democratic parliament.

Comment: @Valorum: ""Ministers", implying some sort of democratic parliament" - ["The Premier represents the government and functions independently. His authority extends over two vice-premiers, 30 ministers (...)"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Korea).

Comment: We are probably seeing only a small part of the big picture (figuratively), but Sisko's stance that "giv[ing] Starfleet direct command of the Federation (...) would make the Federation into a military dictatorship" is curious, given that the depicted "Federation Council" appears to be primarily populated by Starfleet admirals. My out-of-universe guess is that production staff didn't think too hard about what the random assortment of aliens was supposed to depict and went with what was cheaper on the costume department.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Possibly we're only looking at some sort of leadership group consisting of members of the civilian council as well as the Starfleet leadership.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - I assume you're right about the out-of-universe explanation, but in-universe perhaps we could imagine that being a Starfleet official is one of the most well-regarded jobs one can have in the [post-scarcity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-scarcity_economy) society of the Federation, so that voters tend to elect people from Starfleet, and no one sees anything untoward about Starfleet officers wearing their uniforms when doing their duties as members of the Council.

Answer (score 6):

A big clue into their form of government is the fact that they have no monetary policy. They have no money, which means they have no taxes, no expenditures, and no GDP. That raises the question, how do they finance their government? Regardless of what form that government takes, it needs resources to maintain itself.

Given the peace-oriented nature of the Federation, one would assume that those resources are given to the government voluntarily, including human resources in the form of political leadership. People volunteer their leadership in order to be accepted, rejected, or passively allowed, all in a non-forceful manner.

However the relinquishing of Maquis worlds in the Demilitarized Zone to the Cardassians makes one question the extent to which property rights are respected in the Federation. Perhaps there is some coercive system of resource appropriation that finances the government, implying another coercive system to administer it, such as majority rule or some other form of fiat.

Then again the Maquis may not be a property rights issue as much as it is a strategic issue between allied powers at war. The Maquis could be likened to abandoned allies rather than "citizens" as we understand the term.

So it may be fruitful not to think of the Federation as a government at all, but rather a loosely knit alliance of worlds that happens to align under a common understanding of non-intervention, non-interference, and peaceful exchange.

Comment: My answer specifically speaks to finance. All UFP members agree to bear their fair share of the costs of running the Assembly and Star fleet.

Comment: I don't see where. Yours is a fine answer and directly addresses the political question, but I've been puzzled by Federation economics for a very long time, so I chose to answer from that angle.

Comment: It says that the expense of the UFP is borne by all members. The full wording is;

"The Supreme Assembly shall consider and approve the budget of the United Federation of Planets;

The Expenses of the United Federation of Planets shall be borne by the members as apportioned by the Supreme Assembly; 

The Supreme Assembly shall consider and approve any financial and budgetary arrangements[snip]; 

All budgets of, and expenses of the United Federation shall be made and paid in the Common Interplanetary Credit which shall be the official medium of exchange within [UFP Territory]"

Comment: I see where the first part of your reply can be found under the article "Supreme Assembly" but as for the second half of your reply, I still do not see it, especially the part where you mention expenses made and paid in the "Common Interplanetary Credit which shall be the official medium of exchange within [UFP Territory]." That pretty much blows the door off all I knew about Star Trek, which is that there is no official medium of exchange. Nonetheless, your answer does say that expenses are born by all members as apportioned by the Supreme Assembly, but by unanimity or majority? Who knows?

Comment: You have to remember that we don't see the early years of the Federation, we see the creation of the Federation and then spin forward nearly a hundred years to the events of Star Trek TOS. During that period, the UFP clearly encouraged the use of replicators and basically did away with the need for currency of any kind.

As to how the Supreme Assembly makes decisions about finance, each planetary body gets one vote for each of their planets, up to a maximum of 5. Decisions about finance are made unanimously

Comment: The act of relinquishing the Maquis worlds says little about property (or other) rights by itself. The Federation initially trying to *forcibly deport* citizens from those worlds says a huge amount, as does the fact that it was eventually a special extra consideration that they would respect their right to stay on them under Cardassian administration. The Federation generally doesn't seem to acknowledge freedom of movement.

Comment: @Valorum - "All UFP members agree to bear their fair share of the costs" -- money may have been used when the Charter was written but phased out later--in STIV Gillian asks "Don't tell me they don't use money in the twenty-third century" and Kirk says "Well, they don't", and in *First Contact* Picard says "The economics of the future are somewhat different...you see, money doesn't exist in the twenty-fourth century." In the Voyager episode "Dark Frontier" Tom Paris says "the new world economy took shape in the late twenty second century and money went the way of the dinosaur".

Comment: @hypnosifl - They aren't really talking about money but credits that seem to relate to labour and materials. Each participant agrees to provide x worth of whatever is needed. It would also apear that credits are an interplanetary currency rather than one used by the general public

Answer (score 4):

To the best of my understanding, in TOS, the Federation of Planets was loosely based on the United Nations, with Earth the basic equivalent of the United States. The Klingons were the Russians, the Vulcan were Japanese, and the Romulans were the Chinese. This was borne out to some degree in DS9, with the Cardassians playing the role of Germans -- World War II era -- and the Bajorans as occupied France.

Check out Kirk reciting the pledge in the Omega Glory.

Comment: you should post the link to the reciting or quotes it yourself

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean a link to the Omega Glory or the Pledge of Allegiance that Kirk recited? It's the same pledge we did in school.

Comment: *Check out Kirk reciting the pledge in the Omega Glory* I wont check this out... YOU have to answer the question.. there is a good example of a good answer here.. and you can also take the [tour] or visit the [help] or even come see us on Mos Eisly [chat]

Comment: The preamble of the Federation Charter (quoted in other answers) appears to have been modeled directly on that of the UN Charter: http://www.un.org/en/sections/un-charter/preamble/index.html

Comment: I find your 'answer' sickening bigotry and offencive and represents everything Star Trek is not. First of all it is factually incorrect for example you take the racist idea 'the Romulans were the Chinese' Gene based them on Mao's currupt interpretation and realisation of communist China - a political movement not the Chinise as a people. Now if you are Chinese and say therefore you not racist then you go on the say 'Cardassians playing the role of Germans'. In WW2 crimes were perpretrated by Nazi's not Germans a race the same goes for the other races you mention.

Comment: Your whole 'answer' is not supported by any quote or reference it is completely inadequate as ponted out.

Comment: If the Federation is the UN then it confuses things to then say the Klingons were the Russians and the Romulans were the Chinese. After all, the Russians and Chinese are in the UN (with veto power!) but the Klingons and Romulans were not in the Federation.

Answer (score 4):

The Federation is a democracy, although one where Starfleet seems to have a great deal of influence (why are Starfleet admirals sitting on the Federation Council, which is ostensibly a civilian body?) The novel Articles of the Federation goes into greater detail on how the civilian side of the Federation government operates from the viewpoint of President Bacco and her aides.

Answer (score 1):

I just found this place and I think I can help you all out a little bit.  In *Star Trek: Enterprise* the United Earth was established, in the time of the *Enterprise* Series.

The United Earth founded Starfleet and the security council, this is part of the local planetary government of Earth and is Starfleet is the military science branch of United Earth.  The United Federation of Planets is a interstellar governing body that helps organize the member planets that participate in the federation charter which gives all member planets equal access and expenses to scientific research, exploration, and military advancement.

All member planets are organized into home planets and their colonies, The Federation council is the civilian branch of the United Federation of Planets, and consist of representatives of the home system planetary government and their colonies which is governed by the home systems planetary government.

The member planets of the Federation as part of the sharing of the alliance have a few options to pay for membership, bye 1 incurring the cost of Starfleet vessels by creating a starbase or allowing the use of their space port.  Provide officers to Starfleet 3 provide their own fleet for defense.

A good example is Vulcan, a founding member of the United Federation of planets; they provided science officers and their knowledge to the United Federation to pay for their membership, they also maintain their own fleet that can operate within federation controlled space.

The Andorrans have their own fleet and provide technical information and intelligence resource to the Federation  Some member planets only request a fleet when they perceive danger.  Like Betazoid.

You've got to remember the United Federation of Planets is an Alliance type government, and the alliance is organized into sectors consisting of the member home system government and the colonies.

If and when Bajor joins the United Federation of Planets the government of Bajor will still be the Provisional government, it will control its own colonies the Bajorian militia will be absorbed into Starfleet as part of the payment for membership along with the Station *Deep Space 9*.  This is what they can offer to the alliance.

However, because Earth is the capital of the Alliance at least San Francisco is or Federation, the Capital of United Earth is in Europe in France and is suggesting its merging of NATO, EU and other Asian/Pacific islands​ powers as well as the other nation states as members.

Because the United Federation of Planets alliance is within the realm or home range of Earth, the federation council is the civilian branch of the United Federation with the council of jag Officers appointed by Starfleet which operates as checks and balances between the 3 councils and between the planetary government of Earth nation states and the planetary government of other members nation states.

Each planet based on population can vote or appoint a representative (either permanent or temporary) to the Federation council with the option of the home government to recall the member except for the president of the Council,  which is also the president of Earth.  This has been established in both *Star Trek TNG* and *DS9* "Homefront" in "Paradise Lost".

The Federation council can challenge Starfleet through the jag officers which reports directly to Starfleet command.  Starfleet vessels are mandated by the charter to be ships of peace; exploration and all members benefit from the knowledge gathered and collected by Starfleet ships, in times of war all ships and Starfleet officers can be used by the military branch of Earth to thwart enemy advancement and must protect federation member planets at all cost.

I know this is a little confusing I hope you understand this.  The United Federation is like United Earth and Interstellar Alliance combined they are separate and one like the UK.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: Source is in the Television series of Star Trek Enterprise, TNG, Deep Space 9