# What term describes the form of government seen in Star Trek in the TNG era?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

I haven't watched TOS (it's not to my taste), but after watching the whole series of TNG, I liked their system of government (or least what is shown). So what exactly is their system of government, or rather, what would/should it be called?

No currency—everything is provided. Food, entertainment, shelter. No required service or job—it seemed some people didn't even have a job(didn't seem to be a need for one), but still had everything wanted provided for them. There didn't seem to be a supreme leader/figurehead either, but people who would be considered important?

To me, it seems like a utopia. It seems to me a society where everyone has access everything would be great. The goal was that once your superficial needs were met, then you could improve yourself.

Comment: For the record, I voted to close. Your question is both unclear and will invite opinon-based answers

Comment: I know this question may not last, but I'll assert that it appears to be very similar to a Constitutional Republic (operating under a document as its ruling guidelines. The Federation Charter) with a general council (like our Congress in the US) composed of elected representatives from the various member worlds and an elected President, but with socialist utopian services/societal structure.

Comment: While TNG doesn't show it - DS9 which is set in the same timeline and universe shows that there is a President of the Federation and that the position is an elected one - I think that would be a fair answer if somebody cared to take the time, even though it isn't strictly TNG only

Comment: I didn't even think about the others-I've really only seen tng...I guess it would change

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What political system does Star Trek's Federation operate under?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47662/what-political-system-does-star-treks-federation-operate-under)

Comment: For the record I VTC'd this as a duplicate, as did NKCampbell, but as 3 users had already chosen "unclear what you're asking" that is what close reason the system picked.

Answer (score 5):

What you specificially describe is Communism (not to be confused with "Communist States").

Communism is an ideology that aims to create the Communist society - one that features an absence of social classes, money, bureaucracy, power hierachies, wars, nationality and so forth. The motto is "To each according to his needs, from each according to his ability." You could describe it as "equality by freedom, freedom by equality". Production is shared between all members and it stresses democracy and self-rule.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communist_society

Generally Communism is considered to only arise in post-scarcity societies (e.g. when production outscales demand). There are many variants as in every system.

I have to point out here again not to confuse it with the USSR/China/Co. These states proclaimed to have this as their ultimate goal, but striving towards it by doing the exact opposite. However you see it or not, the above definition is what the word stands for - partially. It's hard nowadays, as some Commies are worshipping the USSR while others see it as their worst enemy. In real-life the left is pretty complicated.

I think it's a good fit.

Another somewhat similiar sci-fi universe in that regard you might interesting is "The Culture".

Comment: so it's like a perfected form of communism